# select statement returns null rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

I have a table called `loginaccount` and i need to fetch the password when both `mobileno` and `secrtpin` columns are true or else no output must be displayed

\But the thing is when this statement

```
Select password from loginaccount where secretpin=1050 and mobileno=9551848851
```

`secretepin` is wrong here and the mobile no too,But this statement still returns a null password column, I want password column to be displayed only when where conditions are true or else no output how could i do this

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If your query is really turning up empty when it should not be, then show us some data which supports or does not support this claim.  Also, the relevant Java code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like whatever method you're using to execute

```
Select password from loginaccount where secretpin=1050 and mobileno=9551848851
```

is returning a scalar, not rows. If there are no matching rows, the scalar value *will* be null. If you ask for rows, you should get none, and your code can handle that as appropriate.